# How to configure Flask, WSGI and Apache?

Tags: python, apache, flask, virtualenv, wsgi

I am trying to run a Flask application on my Ubuntu server, using Apache and WSGI and Python3.8.

I started following the [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/) for [mod_wsgi](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/mod_wsgi/).

To setup the project, I followed the [Flask tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/) from the official website.

My root lives in "/var/www/html/base/BE" and it looks like:

```
├── activate_this.py
├── base_be.wsgi
├── be
│   ├── __init__.py
├── be.conf
├── myenv
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── MY_SRC_FILE.py
```

The content of the factory function **./be/**init**.py** is as described on the tutorial, just a "create_app" function with all my initialization.

For **base_be.wsgi**'s content, I followed this [SOq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516248/python-flask-using-mod-wsgi-in-apache-how-to-get-venv-to-work), it does not use the virtual env I have on **myenv**. My file looks like:

```
#/var/www/html/base/BE/myenv/bin/python    
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/base/BE')
    
from be import create_app
application = create_app()
```

If I add **activate_this.py** as suggested on this other [SOq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020451/no-activate-this-py-file-in-venv-pyvenv) with the code shared on this [GitHub](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/main/src/virtualenv/activation/python/activate_this.py):

```
activate_this = '/var/www/html/base/BE/myenv/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

I get the error:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=34272): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/html/base/BE/base_be.wsgi'.
mod_wsgi (pid=34272): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/base/BE/base_be.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/base/BE/base_be.wsgi", line 4, in <module>
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
  File "<string>", line 28, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

On my_application.conf, I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.base
    WSGIDaemonProcess api.base python-path=/var/www/html/base/BE python-home=/var/www/html/base/BE/myenv
    WSGIProcessGroup api.base
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/base/BE/base_be.wsgi 
    <Directory /var/www/html/base/BE/>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And I have added **api.base** to my **/etc/hosts**

Everytime I try to access the application using: api.base/auth/login, I just get error 500.

- How can I have my application running and accessible from "api.base/auth/login"?
- What am I missing here?
- What type of dark magic is happening?

Answer (score 0):

what flask version are you using? 2.0?

im not sure what you want to achive with

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/base/BE')
```

maybe comment it away

and last

the github that you are using it has a comment (https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/tree/main/src/virtualenv/activation)

> Do not use deprecated API

in the python part